# Select first product from first category, then first product from second category and so on

Tags: mysql, select, categories

I need a select query that would fetch the first video from category id 1 and then the first video for category two, then first video for category three and so on for the remaining categories

and then second video for category 1, then second video from category 2 and so on.

This is my database table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE videos(
  video_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  video_filename CHAR(255),
  video_title CHAR(255),
  description CHAR(255),
  video_category INT UNSIGNED,
  video_levels INT UNSIGNED,
  video_type INT UNSIGNED,
  status INT UNSIGNED
);

INSERT INTO videos VALUES
  (1, 'L_1_F_1.mp4', 'Michael Jordan', 'Michael Jordan Footwork', 4, 1, 0, 1),
  (4, 'L_2_B_1.mp4', 'ball', 'handling', 3, 1, 0, 1),
  (3, 'L_1_C_2.mp4', 'Core Training', 'Core Training', 1, 1, 0, 1),
  (5, 'L_1_S_1.mp4', 'Jukes', 'test jukes', 2, 1, 0, 1)
;
```

And the table:

```
| VIDEO_ID | VIDEO_FILENAME |    VIDEO_TITLE |             DESCRIPTION | VIDEO_CATEGORY | VIDEO_LEVELS | VIDEO_TYPE | STATUS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |    L_1_F_1.mp4 | Michael Jordan | Michael Jordan Footwork |              4 |            1 |          0 |      1 |
|        3 |    L_1_C_2.mp4 |  Core Training |           Core Training |              1 |            1 |          0 |      1 |
|        4 |    L_2_B_1.mp4 |           ball |                handling |              3 |            1 |          0 |      1 |
|        5 |    L_1_S_1.mp4 |          Jukes |              test jukes |              2 |            1 |          0 |      1 |
```

See it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2065a/1)

Comment: I think if you can provide your table(s) schema so it can clear your requirement else you should write a query and ask for suggestion or correction(s).

Comment: these are the coloumns                                                               video_id  video_filename  video_title  description  video_category FK of tbl video_category video_levels  video_type 1-youtube,2-others status 1-active,2-inactive

Comment: first row of table  :  1  L_1_F_1.mp4 Michael Jordan  Michael Jordan Footwork 4  1  0  1

Comment: i am unable to add image or provide proper table structure as i can use only comments'

Comment: @Nisha Post table structure and sample data in your **original question** (there is an edit link beneath it) and format it appropriately.

Comment: Fahad, can you please combine these HTMl lines in a file and then try to help me. thanks  :)

Comment: as @peterm said, please edit your original question. This will help no one

Comment: @Nisha, you have only 1 video of each category in your example. Just order them by category then :). Or give a proper example.